# How can I upload a file to Azure Artifacts from my powershell console using Azure DevOps REST Api?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I want to upload a file to Azure Artifacts using the Rest API. Can I do it?

We use on-prem Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Please, note that it is not a nuget or an npm package. It is just a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is not a nuget or an npm package. It is just a file.

If what you want to upload is **files** instead of packages, in Azure devops, I'm afraid only [Universal package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops) can available for files to stored.

BUT, what the issue is Universal package [does not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops-2019#versions-and-compatibility) for Azure devops server. It only support in azure devops service now.

[image]

In our official forum, there has such [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/793825/add-universal-packages-to-devops-server.html) raised to request for this feature added in Azure devops server/TFS. You can vote and share your demand there to raise its  priority. Our product group will review it regularly to consider take some features into develop plan.

Comment: I feel cheated again. The on-prem version of Azure DevOps is just a gift that does not stop giving ...